# Show $\exp$ is complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that for $|z|,|w|\leq r$
$$ \left| \frac{\exp(z)-\exp(w)}{z-w}-\exp(w)\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}\exp(r)|z-w| $$
so that we can deduce the complex differentiability of $\exp$ from $\frac{1}{2}\exp(r)|z-w|\to 0$ for $z\to w$.

Using $z^n-w^n=(z-w)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k w^{(n-1)-k} $ and $\exp(z):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/n! $ I get:

\begin{align*} \left| \frac{\exp(z)-\exp(w)}{z-w}-\exp(w) \right|&= \frac{1}{|z-w|}|\exp(z)-\exp(w)-(z-w)\exp(w)| \\
&= \frac{1}{|z-w|} \left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \left(-w^n+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k w^{n-1-k}\right)(z-w)\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left|\left(\left(\frac{z}{w}\right)^k\frac1w-\frac1n\right)w^n\right|
\end{align*}

From here I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using the relation $\exp(z + w) = \exp(z) \exp(w)$ instead.

Comment: Where would I use this relation? Would I have to put in $\log$'s?

Comment: If you're just trying to show that $\exp$ is differentiable, the above relation reduces it to showing at $z = 0$. If you specifically want to prove the first equation you write, the same technique applies; you'll also want to use the fact that $|e^{\sigma+it}| = e^{\sigma} \leq e^{|\sigma + it|}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another thought: Since $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y +i\sin y)$, show that $e^z$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equations.